# Overlaying an imageview relative to another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

I'm trying to add an ImageView (cirlce avatar) which is aligned to the bottom right of the top bar but with an overlay extending below the bar.

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="#ff652c90">


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/backarrow"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backBtn"
            android:id="@+id/infoLayout"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Lesky"
                android:id="@+id/contactName"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="last online 22/4/2016 11:36 am"
                android:id="@+id/lastSeen"
                android:layout_below="@id/contactName"
                android:textColor="#ffd1d2d4"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/contactpiccirlce"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chatView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chatView"
            android:id="@+id/postArea">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

How can anyone achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="#ff652c90" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/backarrow" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/infoLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backBtn" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Lesky"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastSeen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/contactName"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="last online 22/4/2016 11:36 am"
                android:textColor="#ffd1d2d4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/contactpiccirlce" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstLayout" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/chatView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/postArea"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chatView"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minHeight="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make the height and width 45dp

Comment: This is my XML now http://pastebin.com/4fYTvXWq I don't know if I'm doing something else wrong. Result: http://i.imgur.com/SyXFt2s.png

Comment: I have the full fix one sec

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/infoLayout">

        <ImageButton
             android:layout_width="25dp"
             android:layout_height="25dp"
             android:id="@+id/backBtn"
             android:src="@drawable/backarrow"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:scaleType="fitCenter"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backBtn"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Lesky"
            android:id="@+id/contactName"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backBtn"
            android:text="last online 22/4/2016 11:36 am"
            android:id="@+id/lastSeen"
            android:layout_below="@id/contactName"
            android:textColor="#ffd1d2d4"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/infoLayout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/infoLayout"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/contactpiccirlce"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```